# How to test if a parameter is passed into msi command line?

Tags: wix, custom-action

I am trying to install a msi file using msiexec on Windows. This msi can be installed either into the default ProgramFiles dir or a custom dir specified in the msiexec command.
For example when the custom dir is specified, the command looks like this:

```
msiexec /i installer_name.msi CUSTOM_DIR="C:\TEST" ALLUSERS=1
```

When CUSTOM_DIR is not specified then the command is

```
msiexec /i installer_name.msi ALLUSERS=1
```

For this to work, I am changing a Wix file and creating Custom Action and Custom Action Id.

When CUSTOM_DIR is passed by the installer, then

```
<Custom Action='InstallAppCustom' Before='InstallFinalize'>VersionNT64 and (CUSTOM_DIR) and (ALLUSERS=1)</Custom>
```

and when the CUSTOM_DIR is not passed then

```
<Custom Action='InstallApp' Before='InstallFinalize'>VersionNT64 and (Not CUSTOM_DIR) and (ALLUSERS=1)</Custom>
```

My questions are:

1. Is this the right way to check whether CUSTOM_DIR is passed or not? or any other right way to check it?
2. The issue here is that, irrespective of whether CUSTOM_DIR is passed or not, InstallAppCustom gets executed in the InstallExecuteSequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InstallAppCustom is getting executed everytime because CUSTOM_DIR will be always set. It must have initialized to some default value using Directory table. So, even if you didn't pass parameter, CUSTOM_DIR value will be set.

I understand why you want to check if parameter is passed from command-line but what if user changes CUSTOM_DIR value from UI? If it's not exposed to UI, then it's fine.

So, to check whether a property is passed from command-line, you need set property custom action which should be scheduled as very first action of InstallExecuteSequence, UISequence. Set property action will set CMD_CUSTOM_DIR property and its value would be [CUSTOM_DIR]. This should have condition of CUSTOM_DIR as at this point of installation time, default value of CUSTOM_DIR is not set. So, CMD_CUSTOM_DIR will always have cmdline value if passed and same can be used later on in other custom action conditions.

Comment: After setting the property custom action, how do I change the custom action or custom action Id to search for the dll in the CUSTOM_DIR mentioned? 
Because, my main goal is to search for a DLL inside the CUSTOM_DIR if mentioned or to search for the same dll inside the default installation dir under programfiles

Comment: Is CUSTOM_DIR property your app's installation directory? Is it the only property for setting installation dir?

Comment: sorry I don't get this question. What I have here is, <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="CUSTOM_DIR"/>.

Comment: You don't need to do anything with CUSTOM_DIR property. Just check like this in VBScript:
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

foldername = Session.Property("CUSTOM_DIR")
filename   = "Update.exe"

If fso.FileExists(fso.BuildPath(foldername, filename)) Then
  ' Do your stuff
End If

Answer (score 1):

You can check the log `msiexec /i yourmsi /l*v setup.log`. There all cmd parameters and property changes and values are shown.

Comment: thanks. I did that. I do see that the values are changing as specified in the command line but I am not sure why I see this in the logs for the 
Custom Action  Skipping action: InstallApp(condition is false) irrespective of passing CUSTOM_DIR or not.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer by Vivek helped me to solve the issue I had.
So I implemented something like:

```
<Property Id="DllPath32" Value="[ProgramFilesFolder]\App Name\dependencies"/>
<Property Id="DllPath64" Value="[ProgramFiles64Folder]\App Name\dependencies"/>

<!--CustomAction Id='SetDllPath64' Property='DllPath64' Value='[ProgramFiles64Folder]\\App Name' Return='check' /-->
<!--CustomAction Id='SetDllPath32' Property='DllPath32' Value='[ProgramFilesFolder]\\App Name' Return='check' /-->

<!--Custom Action='SetDllPath64' After='AppSearch'>VersionNT64</Custom-->
<!--Custom Action='SetDllPath32' After='AppSearch'>Not VersionNT64</Custom-->
```

The installation of the app worked as expected. Only issue is that, while uninstalling the app, the ProgramFiles64Folder is not changing to C:\Program Files.